# Will Windows 10 install itself again after I revert back to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I wasn't given a choice and was forced to upgrade from `Win7` to `Win10` and the process took 5 hours. I managed to revert back to my reliable `Win7`.

**My question is**: Now I am worry that `Win10` will force me to upgrade again after reverting. Will that happen? If it may happen again, how can I prevent it from re-installing itself. I really don't want to spend 6-7 hours upgrading and downgrading every 2 days.

---

***Note***: I did some research, and some articles mentioned that users are given 72 hours for the upgrade if they made a reserve for `Win10`. For `Win7` users, the upgrade is optional. But, it wasn't true for me. I've even blocked all Windows update since 2012. But it somehow still downloaded itself and installed itself without my agreement.

Comment: Currently, it's optional for Win7 users. There have been incidents where the upgrade was forced (and then fixed, but to late for some users). MS says it's planning on making the Win10 update a recommended Windows Update in January. There are also certain optional system updates that are for installing Win10 but aren't clearly labeled as such. Personally, I have Windows Update turned off on my Win7 install, updating manually instead. I keep an eye on the technical news regarding the Win10 update and make sure to deny the Win10 update packages as they become known.

Comment: I would recommend to make an image of your current installation. Then you can easily revert to the current state. Here is a tutorial: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/73828-imaging-free-macrium.html?ltr=I

Comment: @Ouroborus Thanks for your comments. I've also turned off Windows auto update (since 2012). But it still forced it's way into my PC and installed itself. After experiencing the horrible experience with Win10, I really want to keep win7 as long as I could. Everything is not working, just a normal start up take 7 minutes every time. The OS is not responsive, and the entire screen is blurred. Not to mention other hardware and drivers related problems.

Comment: `make sure to deny the Win10 update packages as they become known` How do you deny Win10 update? I reject the prompt every time, but it still install itself like a malware without my concern. I am thinking of editing the registry and block certain ports so Windows won't communicate with Microsoft's server, but that is the last resort.

Comment: If you do not install KB3035583 via windows update it will not install again.

Comment: Re: deny Win10 update. For me it's a matter of hiding the various Windows Update packages. As @Moab says, the big one currently is KB3035583. Based on your descriptions, I'd say it had already been installed. Now you're dealing with the Win10 preloader/installer. The questions you get are the installer trying to get started. Read up on removing/disabling the Win10 installer. This seems like a likely candidate: http://serverfault.com/questions/695916/registry-key-gpo-to-disable-and-block-windows-10-upgrade

Comment: @Ouroborus I did a check, what puzzles me is that KB3035583 was not installed. The last windows update I had was installed in 2012. I also checked the win update history. KB3035583 and other updates did not attempt to install itself either. I really don't know what triggered the upgrade and how did it get into my PC.

Comment: @user3437460 Regardless, the question I linked has an accepted answer that should cover you no matter how the Win10 installer got there.

Answer (score 0):

Experience tells me that the answer is no: In all the cases that I saw, even the notification app stopped showing up.

**But why take chances anyway?** You can:

1. Uninstall updates 3173040 and 3035583 if they are installed and blacklist them, so that they are not installed in the future.
2. Disable Windows update for the next 7 days. Microsoft won't release any update during this time anyway because the next Patch Tuesday is at least two weeks away. Just place a reminder somewhere (like a smartphone or calendar app) to remind you to re-enable Windows Update after 29 July.
3. Make sure your computer is equipped with a personal firewall with interactive program control (like Comodo Internet Security, ZoneAlarm, etc.) so that you are notified of any new process attempting to connect to the Internet. Not only this will help you detect and stop the "Get Windows 10" app, but is a general good security suggestion.